# Extracting TTL value of a DNS A record

Tags: c, dns, ttl, libresolv

I am doing some dns stuff and I require to do an A record lookup for an SRV and extract ttl and ip address from it:

I was able to extract ip using the following code, but how do I extract TTL?

```
 l = res_query(argv[1], ns_c_any, ns_t_a, nsbuf, sizeof(nsbuf));
    if (l < 0)
    {
      perror(argv[1]);
    }
    ns_initparse(nsbuf, l, &msg);
    l = ns_msg_count(msg, ns_s_an);
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
      ns_parserr(&msg, ns_s_an, 0, &rr);
      ns_sprintrr(&msg, &rr, NULL, NULL, dispbuf, sizeof(dispbuf));
      printf("\t%s \n", dispbuf);
      inet_ntop(AF_INET, ns_rr_rdata(rr), debuf, sizeof(debuf));
      printf("\t%s \n", debuf);
    }
```

Output:

```
./a.out sip-anycast-1.voice.google.com
        sip-anycast-1.voice.google.com.  21h55m46s IN A  216.239.32.1
        216.239.32.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following mostly your code, you can retrieve the IP and TTL in this way (I fixed up your `ns_parserr()` call so that it iterates through multiple entries in the response properly):

```
    l = res_query(argv[1], ns_c_any, ns_t_a, nsbuf, sizeof(nsbuf));
    if (l < 0) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ns_initparse(nsbuf, l, &msg);
    c = ns_msg_count(msg, ns_s_an);
    for (i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        ns_parserr(&msg, ns_s_an, i, &rr);
        ns_sprintrr(&msg, &rr, NULL, NULL, dispbuf, sizeof(dispbuf));
        printf("%s\n", dispbuf);
        if (ns_rr_type(rr) == ns_t_a) {
            uint8_t ip[4];
            uint32_t ttl = ns_rr_ttl(rr);
            memcpy(ip, ns_rr_rdata(rr), sizeof(ip));
            printf("ip: %u.%u.%u.%u\n", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
            printf("ttl: %u\n", ttl);
        }
    }
```

It produces the following output:

```
$ ./a.out myserver.mydomain.com
myserver.mydomain.com.  1H IN A         172.16.1.21
ip: 172.16.1.21
ttl: 3600
```

I was not able to find very much documentation on the `libresolv` library, and it seems that the shared library `libresolv.so` does not include all the symbols needed to link the program. So, I had to compile the program like this:

```
$ gcc test_resolv.c -static -lresolv -dynamic
```